# Java scheduling tasks. Keep at restart

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, task, scheduling, scheduler

I'm searching for a solution to schedule a task at a given interval,
But I have to be able to **restart** the application and still have it execute the task at the right time.
I don't really want to use any external libraries like Quartz.
Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the start time in a file. Then you can always use the modulo operator to get the next execution time:

```
nextExecutionTime = (startTime - currentTime) % interval + currentTime;
```

Comment: Hmm, now i wonder how i didn't think of that.
Could I manage it with `ScheduledExecutorService` and just do it like this?  
    `ses.schedule(someTask, (lastExecution + interval) - currentTime, TimeUnit.MilliSeconds);`

Comment: Well, then you'd schedule it just one time, but it would give the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linux [crontab](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)  for a schedule a task.In your scenario you can export a jar and schedule it in [crontab](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/).Lets assume your jar is example.jar.

`0 12 * * * java -jar /home/example.jar`

This example.jar will fire at 12pm (noon) every day.